# How to avoid this warning:com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

Tags: java, sax, saxparser

Recently upgraded from JDK1.5 to JDK1.6, during compilation below warning is thrown.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser;

...

org.xml.sax.XMLReader l_oParser = new SAXParser();
```

During compilation

> [javac] C:\Users\project\src\com\test\ecommerce\services\paymentservices\authorization\HistoryTransactionResponseParser.java:14: warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
>   [javac] import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser;

This warning is not shown when compiling with JDK1.5.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the approach suggested in [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) and let the runtime decide the implementation of the SAX parser. Example:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't import stuff from com.sun. It may or may not be around in future releases, which is exactly what the warning is saying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find an alternative to that library. Proprietary means that Sun can remove that package any time they want.

If they decided to remove that from the next JDK release then as soon as you upgraded your JVM it would break everything that relied on that proprietary code.